# Structuremap Constructor Injection for Background Thread in Azure Web Role

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, structuremap, azure-web-roles

I have a background thread running periodically in a windows Azure web role:

```
enquiries = new Enquiry();
Thread enqThread = new Thread(enquiries.Start);
enqThread.Start();
```

Enquiry uses Entity Framework 5.0 DbContext to pull enquiry records from the database.
I want to use Structuremap to inject DbContext in its constructor. I'm doing this,

```
public class Enquiry {

    private readonly IMySiteDb _db;

    public Enquiry(IMySiteDb db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    /*
    Then some methods like Init(), Start(), Execute() etc.
    */
}
```

I have structuremap.mvc installed and initialized objectfactory container with:

```
x.For<IMySiteDb>().HttpContextScoped().Use<MySiteDb>();
```

But initiating **enquiries = new Enquiry();** throws error - *Enquiry does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments*.

I'm quite new to Dependency Injection and could not find how this works for such scenarios. This DI works perfect for controllers. Any idea how this can be done for background threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the object from the container, not by invoking the constructor yourself.

```
enquiries = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<Enquiry >();
```

You typically only want to call the container in one place in your application. That single place is what you call the [Composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).